# Handling TCP connection lost on MySQL C++ Connector

Tags: c++, mysql

How to handle TCP connection lost on MySQL C++ connector?

My code looks roughly like this:

```
sql::Driver* driver = get_driver_instance();
sql::Connection *con = driver->connect("tcp://host:3306", "user", "pass");
sql::PreparedStatement *pstmt = con->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO...");

...

// Set parameters
pstmt->setString(1, "hi");
pstmt->setInt(2, 123);
...

// Perform insertion
pstmt->executeUpdate();
```

The program runs indefinitely and `// Set parameters` and `// Perform insertion` are invoked multiple times. The problem is if the TCP connection is closed (eg: because mysql server restart / timeout) the insertion failed:

```
# ERR: SQLException in ****.cpp(*****) on line 211
# ERR: Lost connection to MySQL server during query (MySQL error code: 2013, SQL
State: HY000 )
```

I've tried setting `OPT_RECONNECT` or `MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT` option to true [as suggested by this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879467/how-to-set-autoreconnect-option-with-mysql-connector-c) but that didn't help

```
sql::Driver* driver = get_driver_instance();
sql::Connection *con = driver->connect("tcp://host:3306", "user", "pass");
bool myTrue = true;
con->setClientOption("MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT", &myTrue); // Or "OPT_RECONNECT"
```

I've tried manually check-and-reconnect before `con->executeUpdate()` using `con->isClosed()` too but still no luck. `con->isClosed()` always returns false even if TCP connection was killed.

I'm compiling against MySQL 5.6 libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is to manually test the connection with simple statement like `SELECT 1` prior to using it:

```
try {
  res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 1");
  delete res; res = NULL;
} catch(sql::SQLException& e) {
  // Connection is lost, reconnect..
  delete pstmt; delete con;
  con = driver->connect(..);
  pstmt = con->prepareStatement(..);
}
```

When connection is lost, the prepared statement object has to be re-created

Other post suggested using [3rd party connection pooling library such as libzdb](http://www.tildeslash.com/libzdb/). Was hoping there's a better & easier alternative.